# Is hand gel effective against Norovirus?

Tags: biology, environmental-health

I saw the following claim in an article in The Guardian - [How not to catch the norovirus](http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2013/jan/06/how-not-to-catch-the-norovirus)

> Incidentally – and you can consider this a public service announcement – forget most hand gels, the majority of which will scarcely dent the norobastard

The hand gel I have on my desk claims it will kill 99.9% of bacteria but makes no specific claims about killing viruses. We have had a question on Skeptics about [soap vs hand sanitizers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2564/which-is-more-effective-at-removing-germs-washing-with-soap-and-water-or-using), but that didn't cover the effectiveness of either method against norovirus.

Is hand gel effective against norovirus (specifically, the hand gel commonly sold to the public - e.g. [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Carex-Hand-Aloe-Vera-93040/dp/B0017TN3XO/ref=pd_cp_beauty_2), [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Purell-Hygienic-Hand-Gel-240ml/dp/B0083RNMAW/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1357563972&sr=8-4) or [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/St-John-Ambulance-Hand-Sanitizer/dp/B0029LHCKY/ref=tag_dpp_lp_edpp_ttl_in))?

Comment: “killing viruses” – how can you kill that which is not alive? ;-) … Incidentally, I’m not sure what the sceptical claim here is: none of these hand gels claim to be effective against viruses. There’s no reason to suspect that they are.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It gives people a false sense of security. I see a lot of my coworkers rely heavily on hand gel but do not take any other precautions. Most people do not even know the difference between 'germs'. I just recently had a discussion about antibiotics and viruses.

Comment: @Stefan Sure but that isn’t a notable claim per se. People simply don’t read the labels. But I don’t think there’s a pervasive myth, carried by any kind of media, that hand gel is an effective virus killer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the company I work for is distributing bottles of hand sanitiser to "prevent the spread of Norovirus", so I would argue that the claim is notable in the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hand-sanitisers are available which are advertised as destroying viruses.

For example

[image: Can of Virashield]

This one claimns to contain ["byotrol anti-microbial technology"](http://www.byotrol.co.uk/byotrol_protects.html) a proprietary product which claims

> It kills and destroys bacteria **and viruses** but here’s the clever bit; it then dries to form an invisible barrier which keeps on working to stop germs from coming back for up to 24 hours on surfaces you use daily.

(my emphasis)

A [press release](http://www.cisionwire.com/media-intelligence-partners-ltd/r/press-release--nhs-hand-wash--ineffective--against-superbugs,c473699) of Byotrol PLC says

> The research, carried out by the Agri-Food and Biosciences Institute (AFBI), on behalf of anti-infection firm Byotrol, measured Byotrol hand-foam, NHS hand-gel (Spirigel), Vick’s First Defence and Dettol hand-foam on their performance in killing dangerous viruses 24 hours after application. 
>   The tests looked at which products prevent viruses returning for up to 24 hours after application. Worryingly, the NHS “gold standard” hand-gel offered no residual effect whatsoever. 
>   After 24 hours, First Defence continued to be effective against 90 per cent of the sample, a surrogate for Norovirus (Feline Calicivirus), with Dettol hand-foam remaining 50 per cent effective and the NHS standard hand-gel offering no ongoing protection at all.
>   Byotrol hand-foam, the only product not based on alcohol, remained effective with a 99.9 per cent kill rate, 24 hours after application.
>   The results are in line with last year’s study at Manchester Royal Infirmary,

I can't find independent references for these claims however.

---

If a hand-sanitizer product doesn't even claim to destroy viruses, there are probably good grounds for suspecting that it doesn't.